# How to play when you block all your opponents' value range

Tags: nlhe, cash-game, nuts

This is a generic question on what is a good strategy when flopping the nuts like quads, particularly when there are no scare cards on turn/river. It seems like any quads always freeze action because you're afraid of scaring opponents off the pot, but theres also no real way for your opponents to bet without some value.

EG. 9max 1/2 live cash game, about 100-200BB deep.

Hero raises AQs in UTG+1, CO calls, Button calls, BB calls.

Flop is Q Q 2 rainbow. Should Hero bet trying to stack the last Q? Or get 1-2 streets of value from a middling pair? Hero checks to induce a bluff/let opponents catch up. Checks through.

Turn is Q. Now if BB had 22 it is counterfeited. Hero checks thinking that a pocket pair will likely valuebet in position, while a dead hand like middling cards can pair the river and call a bet. Checks through.

River is 2. Now everything is counterfeited. The way it is played, it is likely everyone else is playing the board. Should Hero bet and hope someone bluff-catches? what sizing would that be? Unlikely for someone to bluff since playing the board arguably has "showdown" value, and the pot is too small to get tricky.

Good if answers can also generally cover how quads is approached. Or if tournament play would differ.

Comment: About 1-200BB deep? Is that sarcastic? Probably a preflop shove 1BB deep. I wouldn't say you are blocking all of your opponent's value range, though. There are plenty of pocket pairs still there

Comment: i mean 100-200B. like, one to two hundred BB. Everyone is vaguely at that stack depth, and with the action i didnt see a need to give more detail. You are right on the 2nd part, although it gets less likely once they check back twice.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right way to approach this is to think about how you would play the part of your range that does not contain a Q. In order to not play your hand effectively face up, you must decide which hands you would play as if you had AQ. Which hands would those be? There are no draws possible. How about other value hands, like AA, KK, A2s? The problem is, if play all those as if you were trying to stack KQ, ie. check/raise the flop, what will happen is that 1) you will lose value when your opponent checks behind with a hand that would have called e.g. a 1/3-pot bet, 2) you get stacked, when you run your AA into 22. And since you would presumably also check/fold a lot of hands in this spot, you deny yourself a lot of fold equity.

In conclusion: The correct approach in this spot is to bet small with your entire range.

Comment: play like your bluffing

Comment: @Jon That's not very helpful. How *would* you play, if you were bluffing? Would you lead big? Would you check/raise? And how would you avoid capping your range, when you have a strong, but not nutted value hand?

Answer (score 0):

last timr I flopped quads I was able to get it all in on the flop loosing a once in a life time chance to make a superstar laydown on the river full board runout was 10 9 9 4 10 like any hand you figure out how much they are willing to pay, and send them the bill or overcharge depending on your objective.